# How can I increment the value for each INSERT INTO iteration?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Query as shown below
column1 is int
anothercolumn is varchar(100)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (column1,column2)
SELECT (MAX(column1) FROM TABLE1)+1 ,anotherColumn FROM TABLE2
```

Table1 Before Query

```
column1  column2
-------  -------
3         test1
4         test2
```

Table1 After Query

```
column1  column2
-------  -------
3         test1
4         test2
5         anotherVal1
5         anotherVal2
5         anotherVal3
```

But I want

```
column1  column2
-------  -------
3         test1
4         test2
5         anotherVal1
6         anotherVal2
7         anotherVal3
```

How can I achieve this in SQLserver 2008 StoredProcedure?
I always assumed that Queries are iterated and they would check the condition for each rows. But it seems like aggregate function executes only once!

**EDIT 1**

Please answer this too
After only completing the SELECT statement the INSERT would work.  Thats why I didn't get result as expected??? Am I correct?

Comment: are you sure you don't want an identity for this column? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174639.aspx

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I can't use it in my context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use [row_number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to give your rows sequential numbers

```
insert into Table1 (column1,column2)
select 
    (select max(column1) from Table1) + row_number() over (order by T2.anotherColumn),
    T2.anotherColumn
from Table2 as T2
```

or more safe version (it would work even if you don't have any rows in Table1):

```
insert into Table1 (column1,column2)
select 
    isnull(T1.m, 0) + row_number() over (order by T2.anotherColumn),
    T2.anotherColumn
from Table2 as T2
    outer apply (select max(column) as m from Table1) as T1
```

Comment: After only completing the SELECT statement the INSERT would work. Am I correct? Thats why I didn't get result as expected???

Comment: insert is working as insert of bunch of rows, and that's why your statement insert one column1 for all rows, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is answered already but maybe the solution can even be simplified further? What about

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (column1,column2)
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT MAX(column1) FROM TABLE1),0)
 +ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY anotherColumn),
 anotherColumn FROM TABLE2
```