# How to prevent non-unique values based on another field in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a Hotel Management System in ASP.NET MVC for college and came across an issue I couldn't seem to figure out with Entity Framework.

I have a table in my database named "rooms", which is used to store the Hotel ID, Room Type ID, Room Number (as in the number you see on the door when you try to find your room), Current Rate, and it's Primary Key - Room ID.

See design view [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Zkm.png).

I wish for the Room Number to automatically increment on insert, based on the Hotel ID. For Example, consider the latest room number for hotel #1 is 3 and the latest for hotel #2 is 7. If a row is inserted for hotel #1, the room number will be set as 4; if it was inserted for hotel #2, then it would be 8.

I tried researching unique constraints, to see if they would accomplish this goal. So if the administrator using the admin panel on my web app entered a room number that exists for that hotel, it would just through an error.

After a while I thought about potentially automating the process, but was not sure if it is possible.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: There is no out of the box functionality for this, you would simply need to find the maximum and add one to it. [This answer should help you with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18159959/1048425). A Unique constraint is definitely a good idea to prevent people overriding the insert behaviour and adding duplicate rooms. Finally, this seems to have limited scope, most hotels I have been to number their rooms based on floor, and don't have unbroken sequences of rooms (e.g. 101, 102, 103, 104, 201, 202, 203, 204...).

Comment: If I was a hotel administrator using your admin portal, I would probably rather just have the highest room number + 1 pre-populate on the data entry form, and have the ability to amend this, than have the room number generation completely automated.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.

Your comment worked great. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted

Comment: @GarethD, please post as solution